# Firebase Database change key(copy to new path delete old path) crashes my app

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

In my app every user has a unique username i keep user data like this:

```
root:
  +users:
    +ricksanchez:
      +name:"Rick Sanchez";
      +email:"rick@sanchez.com";
      +bio:"I'm super smart";
      +followers:
        +follower1:morty;
        +follower2:summer;
```

When i wanna change username i have to change database key but firebase doesnt have any method to do that so im using below code:

```
private void copyRecord(DatabaseReference fromPath, final DatabaseReference toPath) {
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            toPath.setValue(dataSnapshot.getValue()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isComplete()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Success!");
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Copy failed!");
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    };
    fromPath.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
}
```

This code works perfect on first time but when i run this code second time without closing app,app crashes but when i run app again after crashed works perfect but again second time it crashes

Also im using this code in fragment and i load my fragment whit this code:

```
public void pushFragment(Fragment fragment){
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.mainframe,fragment).hide(getCurrentFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
```

My error log:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment UsernameChangeFragment{2a2928de} not attached to a context.
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.requireContext(Fragment.java:693)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:757)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getString(Fragment.java:779)
    at sonata.com.sonata.Util.UsernameChangeFragment$2$1.onDataChange(UsernameChangeFragment.java:90)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzfc.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzgx.zzdr(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzhd.run(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

Do you have any idea why?

edit: My crashing fragment code:

```
usernameedittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(text.length()>0){
                if(!text.toString().equals(username)){
                    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(text.toString());

                    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if(!dataSnapshot.exists()){







                                /* this is my error line*/ uyarıtext.setText(getString(R.string.youcantakethisusername));







                                uyarıtext.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00ff00"));
                                uyarıtext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                            else{
                                uyarıtext.setText(getString(R.string.usernametaken));
                                uyarıtext.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
                                uyarıtext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }
                else{
                    uyarıtext.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                }

            }
            else{
                uyarıtext.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });


        savebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("1","butona tıklandı");

                    if (usernameedittext.getText().toString().length() > 0 && !usernameedittext.getText().toString().equals(username)) {
                        Log.i("2","yeni username kriterleri uygun");

                        yeni.child(usernameedittext.getText().toString()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                                    Log.i("3","kullanıcı adı uygun");

                                    copyRecord(eski, yeni.child(usernameedittext.getText().toString()));
                                    Log.i("15","copyrecord bitti");
                                } else {
                                    uyarıtext.setText(getString(R.string.usernametaken));
                                    uyarıtext.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
                                    uyarıtext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });

                    }

            }

        });
```

Also my register fragment crash with same error;

```
username.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int before, int count) {


            if (text.length()>0) {


                database.child("users").child(text.toString()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                            uyarıtext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            uyarıtext.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.youcantakethisusername));
                            uyarıtext.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00ff00"));
                        } else {
                            uyarıtext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

/* this is my error line */

uyarıtext.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.usernametaken));

```
                            uyarıtext.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
            else{
                uyarıtext.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });



    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("1","butona tıklandı");
            if(namesurname.getText().toString()!=null&&email.getText().toString()!=null&&password.getText().toString()!=null){
                Log.i("2","edittextler boş değil");
                progressDialog.show();
                Log.i("3","propgres gösterildi");
                    database.child("users").child(username.getText().toString()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                                Log.i("4","girilen kullanıcı adı alınabilir");
                                if (isValidEmail(email.getText().toString())) {
                                    Log.i("5","e posta geçerli");
                                    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                try {
                                                    throw task.getException();
                                                } catch (FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException e) {
                                                    uyarıtext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                    progressDialog.hide();
                                                    uyarıtext.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
                                                    uyarıtext.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.weakpassword));
                                                } catch (FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException e) {
                                                    uyarıtext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                    progressDialog.hide();
                                                    uyarıtext.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
                                                    uyarıtext.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.invalidemail));

                                                } catch (FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException e) {
                                                    uyarıtext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                    progressDialog.hide();
                                                    uyarıtext.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
                                                    uyarıtext.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.emailtaken));

                                                } catch (Exception e) {

                                                }
                                            } else {
                                                Log.i("6","kullanıcı oluşturudu");

                                                DatabaseReference ref = database.child("users").child(username.getText().toString());
                                                Log.i("7","username'e refereans oluşturuldu");
                                                DatabaseReference refuidusername = database.child("uidusername").child(auth.getUid());
                                                Log.i("8","uid refereansı oluşturuldu");
                                                refuidusername.setValue(username.getText().toString());
                                                Log.i("9","uidusername değeri yazıldı");
                                                User user = new User();
                                                Log.i("10","yeni user oluşturuldu");
                                                user.setUId(auth.getUid());
                                                Log.i("11","yeni useruid değeri yazıldı");
                                                user.setNamesurname(namesurname.getText().toString());
                                                Log.i("12","yeni user adsoyad değeri yazıldı");
                                                user.setEmail(email.getText().toString());
                                                Log.i("13","yeni user email değeri yazıldı");
                                                ref.setValue(user);
                                                Log.i("14","databse bu yser verileri yüklendi");
                                                progressDialog.hide();
                                                Log.i("15","progresdialog gizlendi");
                                                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                                Log.i("16","gragmenttransaction.getfragmentmanager.begintransaction");
                                                for (int i = 0; i < getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount(); i++) {
                                                    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();

                                                }
                                                Log.i("17","backstack temizlendi");
                                                ft.replace(R.id.mainframe, new MainFragment()).commit();

                                            }
                                        }
                                    });


                                } else {
                                    toast(getResources().getString(R.string.invalidemail));
                                    progressDialog.hide();

                                }

                            } else {
                                uyarıtext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                uyarıtext.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.usernametaken));
                                uyarıtext.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
                                progressDialog.hide();

                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely **not** a Firebase issue. The error says that your `UsernameChangeFragment` is not attached to a context which means that your fragment doesn't belong to an activity. To solve this, everytime you need to use the `context`, simply check the activity for nullity:

```
Activity activity = getActivity();
if(activity != null) {
    //Your logic
}
```

There is also another option which implies the use of the [isAdded()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isAdded()) method which is one of the fragment methods that can help you identify if the current fragment is attached to its activity or not.

```
if(isAdded()) {
    //Your logic
}
```

Comment: I have one more fragment,with that fragment i edit firebase data but that fragment never crash so this error should be special to this fragment. What thing detach my fragment from context? What do you think about that? Also I'm really beginner level of android coding if i ask stupid questions please forgive me but Where should I put check activity code or  isadded method and what should i type in it? For example if(getactivity!=null){attachmyfragment} or if(idAdded()){.  What should I type here?}

Comment: Also I have only one activity I handle everything with fragments

Comment: Make that check in everywhere you need the context. Be sure your fragment is attached to the activity.

Comment: Thats the problem im really new on android coidng and i dont know when i need context. I have edited my question can you edit my code and give me an example? My crashing fragments code is bottom of question.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question or is the same one?

Comment: It gives me same error. and i have already added and i just realized my user register fragment also crash with same error.Do you want me to add register fragment code? Maybe they have common code mistake or different thing?

Comment: Yes you can add it.

Comment: I have added. For you to know my usernamechange fragment change username copy all data to new key and delete old data then crash, And my register fragment it create user , upload user data to database then crash.

Comment: Please inidcate the line at which the crash occurs.

Comment: In error code there is no specific line.To find out which line gives error i add log method after every line of code.But the problem is every line is working. App crashes when there is no code to run.

Comment: I have added my code with logs it run all codes until log14 but it never show log15

Comment: There should be a particular line at which that error occurs, so you should indicate me that line.

Comment: it give me error when i try to take a string from string.xml file.In this case my error is in text.settext(getstring(R.string.sometext));  also i havent add here but my fragment have edittext listener to check if username is exist. And error line is in listener i will point my error line and update my fragments code

Comment: This sounds as another problem. So as I understand, you aren't getting `IllegalStateException: Fragment UsernameChangeFragment{2a2928de} not attached to a context` anymore, right?

Comment: No i still have same error "fragment is not attached to a context". I have updated my fragments code and pointed error line please check

Comment: I'm sorry but there are to many errors I can figure it out in your code right now. The solve for the initial problem lies in my answer above. I recommend you to take one problem at the time and post other questions containing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with that, so me or other users can help you.